# How can I add a sub drop down menu to the <a href="#">Link 3</a> in the dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code below, I am having trouble adding Link 3 in the drop down menu seems like that every time I add this it does not accept it a creates a new specific sub list that is not associated. Tried locating more info on the web but nothing concrete, Any ideas? Trying to apply dropdown submenu into the code.

  -

---

1. > **List item**

=======

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_layout.css">
  <title>Travel Agency</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">
        <a class="active" href="#home"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100px"></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow preview shows the correct dropdown menu... what's the problem on it?

Comment: I am trying to add like a sub menu to <a href="#">Link 3</a>, for example when hoverring on link3 to give me another dropdown so that I may add new             <a href="#"></a>

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a dropdown submenu but having trouble with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, tried this, but it's not the cleanest way to do it

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown , .dropdown2{
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn, .dropdown2 .dropbtn2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn , 
.dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2{
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content, .dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a, .dropdown-content2 a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover, .dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content, .dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="#home">
                    <a class="active" href="#home"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100px"></a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">
                            Dropdown 
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                <div class="dropdown2" style="float: none;">
                                    <button class="dropbtn2" style="color: black">
                                        Dropdown 2
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-content2">
                                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                                        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                                        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this is something that I was trying to achieve with the dropdown but it still does not allow to hover over the 2 links bellow as it openes a new dropdown on the third, is there a way for the sub dropdown to be floated left?